# Cannot make any DataGridViewCellEventHandler events works

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been trying so many different ways to try and trigger events based on clicks within my datagridview.
First I'd like to put up a basic [example from MDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick.aspx), then I'd like to put something I am using for another click event that does work, and hopefully someone can explain what I'm doing wrong and why one way is working versus another not working.

```
    public event DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler CellMouseClick;
    private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Text.StringBuilder cellInformation = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        cellInformation.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "ColumnIndex", e.ColumnIndex);
        cellInformation.AppendLine();
        cellInformation.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "RowIndex", e.RowIndex);
        cellInformation.AppendLine();
        MessageBox.Show(cellInformation.ToString(), "CellMouseClick Event");
    }
```

Mind you, I have also tried removing this public event call as well.  Additionally, I get a tooltip that shows up on the CellMouseClick portion of the public event call that says I never use the CellMouseClick item.

For another Mouse Click event I wanted to detect, the below managed to work, but it seems to take more to get it to work and the above seems like it's supposed to work so seamlessly, so I'd prefer to get the above to work as it is intended.
Here is the working version.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView_MouseDown);
        this.toolStripMenuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuStrip1_Click);

    }

private void dataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            try
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Cells[1];
                this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.dataGridView1, e.Location);
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain more what you mean that it takes you more work? also    this.dataGridView1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView_MouseDown); can be just    this.dataGridView1.MouseDown += dataGridView_MouseDown;

Comment: @dshun Just seems like more variables need to be established, but regardless of my opinion, the fact remains that simple code that seems to be the preferred method, and that should work, isn't working, and I'd like to know how to fix it...

Comment: hi, i actually tried your code, it works. one thing might help if you debug (f5), to see if anything goes wrong. also try to check if there is any exception

Comment: hi, TekGiant, curious if the code has worked for you. By the way, for your question, i do not think your code is inherently problematic. other than that, you have the contextmenu show twice. and you are not consistent with how you use your controls. Sometimes you call it this.dataGridView1, sometimes you use this.contextMenuStrip1, then another time it is just dataGridView and contextMenuStrip. If you have resharper, you will this keyword is redundant in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time looking around, I managed to find the actual answer.

I don't quite remember where I found it, but what I was missing was this call:

```
    dataGridView1.CellMouseClick += dataGridView1_CellMouseClick;
```

the MSDN website seemed to indicate that this was the call to be made before the event handler:

```
    public event DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler CellMouseClick;
```

The ladder of these 2 does not work.  If the above person who tried to answer this did get it to work, I would imagine the user added something they knew to add due to experience and probably assumed I was doing it.  So, just for clarity here is the end product that causes the event to work:

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.CellMouseClick += dataGridView1_CellMouseClick;
    }


    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //whatever you want to happen when the mouse is clicked in a cell.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code works. I tried it. Since i do not have the full code, it is hard to know exactly where goes wrong.

one thing to note is, the catch(exception) does not really do anything, which cause any exceptions just pass without notice. You may have had some exceptions. Try to print out exception information or handle any exception gracefully.

```
         catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```